# Only allow properties of class to be used as method parameter

Tags: c#

How can I ensure that only a `static readonly string` within a class is used as a parameter for a method? Obviously I can use a regular string as a method parameter but this means that basically anything can be passed into the method.

An example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        public static class Foo
        {
            public static readonly string Bar = "this is effectively a configuration value";
            public static string CoolMethod(string bar)
            {
                if (bar == "this is effectively a configuration value")
                {
                    return "Here is the info you wanted";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "no";
                }
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = Foo.CoolMethod(Foo.Bar);
            Console.WriteLine(test);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to ensure that only a property of `Foo` (such as the string, `Bar`) can be used as a parameter for `CoolMethod`. There may be more than one string property in the class that is allowed to be passed in. Is this possible?

The use case is to pass various template values into a method which returns a `UriTemplateMatch` object but I want to limit what can be passed in so that templates can be maintained in one place, rather than randomly written in numerous places.

Comment: How about an `enum` as the type of the paramater, on which values you decide what to retrieve?

Comment: Why are you allowing a parameter within your method to begin with if you only want it to be the `Bar` property?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yeah I noticed the mistake with the If - will fix it in a min. I was trying to post a simple bit of code that can easily be amended, rather than trying to obfuscate all my business logic and proprietary stuff, hence the foo/bar (which I hate, btw)

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne There are multiple (very similar) parameters in the real method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would set up an enum to represent the configuration properties and use that as a parameter to the method:

```
public enum ConfigOption
{
    Foo,
    Bar
}

private static Dictionary<ConfigOption, string> _configLookup = new Dictionary<ConfigOption, string>
{
    { ConfigOption.Foo, "Foo" },
    { ConfigOption.Bar, "Bar" }
};

public static string CoolMethod(ConfigOption configOption)
{
    if (!_configLookup.TryGetValue(configOption, out string value))
    {
        // Handle error
    }

    // Use value retrieved from dictionary.
}
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter I might have been inferring something not there, but thought maybe the string would be used to retrieve a value from App.config or similar. I don't tend to hardcode configuration values. In fact, I almost used `key` instead of `value`.

Comment: I think the Dictionary is an overkill, nonetheless, it's a fine way to achieve the result.